# Xcode 9 export xcarchive to IPA gives crashess xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, bitcode

In Xcode9 when I try to export xcarchive with compileBitcode it crashes and shows me the following error

```
  {
            code = 0;
            description = "Failed to verify bitcode in XXXX.framework/XXXXX:\nerror: Platform iPhoneSimulator is not supported\n\n";
            info =             {
            };
            level = ERROR;
            type = "malformed-payload";
  },
```

When I run the same framework on simulator separately it runs perfectly

I have enabled bitcode on my framework using `ENABLE_BITCODE` I have also added

```
BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE = bitcode
```

And added 
`-fembed-bitcode` to other linker flags and other c flags

Also when I run

```
otool -l XXXX.framework/XXXX | grep __LLVM
```

It returns `segname __LLVM`

Comment: Might be a stupid question but how about disabling bitcode? Have you tried it?

Comment: I need bitcode. Offcourse disabling bitcode it works fine